# Meaning of apply = TRUE/FALSE in collapse: settransformv

Tags: r

I am struggling to understand what apply = TRUE/FALSE means within collapse: settransformv. Maybe somebody can give a hand on this? Below I am adding an example where a code fails when I specify apply = TRUE.

```
library(collapse)
library(data.table)

lagamount <- 1

testdf_1 <- data.table(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                     counter = as.integer(c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,11,12)),
                     xval = seq(100, 1000, 100))

testdf_2 <- copy(testdf_1)


settransformv(testdf_1, "xval", flag, 1:3, group, counter, apply = FALSE)
settransformv(testdf_2, "xval", flag, 1:3, group, counter, apply = TRUE)
```

Comment: From the manuals: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/collapse/collapse.pdf , apply = TRUE applies to all columns, FALSE applies it to selected columns, see page: 112

Comment: @zx8754 this is not true. If I understand correctly then apply = TRUE also applies to selected columns

Comment: Not familiar with the package, but the manual has the definition.

Comment: @zx8754 in the manual it says: FUN(get_vars(.data, vars), ...), vars in this case are 1:3

Answer (score 0):

So the apply argument is there mainly because all `.FAST_FUN` in the package have a data.frame method, which is more efficient than applying the function to multiple columns using `lapply`, espeically if some grouping/indexing is done in the call. This example should clarify it.

```r
library(collapse)
library(magrittr)
library(microbenchmark)

# These two are equivalent
settransformv(wlddev, PCGDP:POP, flag, 1, iso3c, year)
fselect(wlddev, PCGDP:POP) %<>% lapply(flag, 1, wlddev$iso3c, wlddev$year)
# -> so here we redo the indexing for each column

# These two are also equivalent
settransformv(wlddev, PCGDP:POP, flag, 1, iso3c, year, apply = FALSE)
fselect(wlddev, PCGDP:POP) %<>% flag(1, wlddev$iso3c, wlddev$year)
# -> we only index once, so this is efficient

# To prove the point:
microbenchmark(A = settransformv(wlddev, PCGDP:POP, flag, 1, iso3c, year), 
               B = settransformv(wlddev, PCGDP:POP, flag, 1, iso3c, year, apply = FALSE))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq       max neval
#>     A 485.276 578.5715 1354.6314 610.572 653.7245 31025.151   100
#>     B 211.232 243.4785  264.8313 262.031 284.4375   320.497   100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that for a single column there are no benefits to setting `apply = FALSE`, except if you have a function that only operates on data frames. For the single column case you also don't need to use the (v) version of the function, but can simply do

```
settransform(wlddev, PCGDP_lag = flag(PCGDP, 1, iso3c, year))
```